# Wordpress core jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, conflict

```
function my_customize_scripts(){
wp_register_script('my-customizer-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/customizer.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
wp_enqueue_script('my-customizer-js');
}add_action('customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'my_customize_scripts', 1);
```

jQuery file enqueue with hook `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` works only when page starts to load, but when loaded it's just stop working. And worse, all the `.change()` functions' execution result desapears. It worked fine before, and three days earlier just stop working.
This file, `customizer.js` has to enqueue with this hook `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`, it will not work in customizer other wise. Well, at least as I know, cause I tried all other hooks.

This is how jQuery code wrapped in `customizer.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//code here
}
```

inside has `change()` functions for elements depends on input.

I tried to `wp_derejister_script('jquery');` to dequeue the wordpress core jQuery and then add hardcoded Google api just before `wp_head` in my `header.php`, like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it worked, but it's not an option. I want the Wordpress core jQuery run on my website.
 I tried to undo all the changes that I've done to `customizer.js` when it stopped working. Also I tried to reduce this file, and took off all events, except one. It didn't help either.
But the `alert();` that I put inside function is working just fine BTW.

So please, any help is appreciated.

P.S. I checked other js files, as I can see they work fine. I also tried to enqueue customizer.js the general way `wp_enqueue_script()` guess what, you right - it didn't work.
This is my first time I am asking question here, this is my last hope.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_register_script` has a `$required` parameter - so any (other) JS "requiring" jQuery will cause WP to re-initialize and include it.

The trick is to replace the `jquery` script by re-registering with your own.

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');  // remove WP jquery that relies on v1
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js', array(), $ver, true );
```